# How to save data to a text file from several text boxes to a text file

Tags: c#

I am developing awindows form application with one button. Each time I press the button it will generate text boxes. For example if I click that button 5 times, 5 text boxes will be there. Now user will enter data to those text boxes. And when he will press enter(another button) it has to store to a text file. I struct at this point as I am generating text boxes during run time.
Can any one help me out.

my code is

private void create_pos(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter_1++;

```
        if (counter_1 == count)
        {
            left += 300;
            top = 50;
            count = count + 25;

        }
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

        Button newButton = new Button();
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);
        newButton.Left = left;
        newButton.Top = top;



            TextBox newtextbox = new TextBox();

        Controls.Add(newtextbox);


        if (counter_1 == 100)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        newtextbox.Left = left + 100;
        newtextbox.Name = "text" + counter_1;

       // TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt", true);
        //tsw.WriteLine(newtextbox.Text);
       // tsw.Close();

        newtextbox.Top = top;
        top += newButton.Height + 2;
        newButton.Text = "position" + counter_1;


        textBox1.Text = newtextbox.Name;
    }
    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control item in Controls)
        {

            if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                savetext[counter_1] = item.Text.ToString();
            }



            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("d:\\test.txt", savetext.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Someone will help you, if you include the code that you have tried

Comment: Is your problem in saving the data or reading the data from generated text boxes?

Comment: problem in saving data.

Comment: replace savetext.ToString() with string.Join(seperator string, savetext); seperator string can be any string even empty string like string.Empty;

Comment: ' string filePath = "d:\\test.txt";
            StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Control item in Controls)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    contentBuilder.Append(((TextBox)item).Text);
                }
            }
            string content = contentBuilder.ToString();
            if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content)))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                { writer.Write(content); }'

Comment: in the above code i cant save data from difrent textboxses in diffrent line. what to do

Answer (score 1):

I would keep track of your dynamic text boxes so that you can differentiate between the ones you are concerned with now and any other text boxes that might already be on the form, or that you might add later. I'll assume that, as you generate a TextBox and add it to the form, you also store a reference to it in a list, e.g.

```
List<TextBox> dynamicTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
```

In the event handler for the Enter key (or any other event handler that you want to trigger the writing), you can gather the text from the controls and write it out. It isn't clear exactly what your requirement is here, so let's write a function that accepts a list of TextBox and a file name to write the text to, one line at a time

```
private void WriteTextBoxes(string path, List<TextBox> textBoxes)
{
    // Here we use some Linq to quickly get all of the text, but you could
    // also use an explicit loop
    string text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBoxes.Select(t => t.Text));
    File.WriteAllText(path, text);
}
```

You could then call that method from your event handler, passing in the list of dynamic TextBox controls

```
WriteTextBoxes(@"C:\Temp\My.txt", dynamicTextBoxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the controls on your form using this.FindControl method and check if it is text box. If it is text box read the content using its .Text property. Use loop to iterate through the controls.

If you are not mainting a list of generated controls then do this:

```
string filePath = "path to text file";
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Control item in Controls)
{
     //i don't remember if this check would work. if it doesn't work try item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)
     if (item is TextBox)
     {
          contentBuilder.Append(((TextBox)item).Text);
     }
}

string content = contentBuilder.ToString();

if(!string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(content))
{
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        //check if Write or WriteLine or something else would work.
        writer.Write(content);
    }
}
```

if you are using list to maintain the generated controls then just change the for part of the loop.

Comment: no need to do find control. Just iterate through collection of controls on your form.

Comment: It would be more elegant and efficient to keep track of the dynamic controls (e.g. a List). In particular that allows you to differentiate between text controls that are already on the form (or may be added later) vs. the dynamic controls. Also "do your processing" is a core part of the question.

Comment: @Eric: Agreed "do your processing" is core part of the question but he hasn't posted any thing about how he intends to save the data. I assumed he isn't able to find the controls on his Form. I will update my answer and I agree he should maintain a list of controls.

Comment: Do you get any error/exception or content is not saved in the file?

Comment: the culprit is savetext.ToString(). It will give you System.String[]. do a join of all the strings in the string array.

Comment: string.Join(seperator, saveText); seperator can be any string even emptry string string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is, Iterate through the child controls of type `TextBox` then Collect its Texts and make a string with those collected values. Now you have the text to write to the file and a path of the file. Then you can use `File.WriteAllText` method to perform the action:

```
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (TextBox dynamicText in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    contentBuilder.AppendFormat("Text in {0} is {1} \n", dynamicText.Name, dynamicText.Text);
}
string pathOfFile = @"path here";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathOfFile,contentBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: That assumes that there are no non-dynamic TextBox controls on the form (now or in the future). May or may not be a valid assumption, but it is a fragile one (breaks easily with future code maintenance).